# jquery generating a delimited string, from select

Tags: php, jquery

From dropdownlist user can select option and click button to add that option to textbox. At the same time I want to add that that text to hidden field joined each option with "|" deliminator.

```
<select id="services" multiple>
        <option>Mobile</option>
        <option>Computer</option>
        <option>Electronic</option>
</select>

$( "#services-add" ).click(function() {
//here when this button clicked I want to add options to hidden field(already created) as string with deliminator 
}
```

Here is hidden field that I want to append text

```
<input type="hidden" name="value" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` to collect all selected data into array and stored to hidden field using `attr`

```
$("#services-add").click(function () {
    var val = $("#services option:selected").map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
     $("[type=hidden][name=value]").attr("value", val);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CQAHq/3/)

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you didn't understand the quetion correctly. User can add multiple options by clicking button. It should be a string which hold all those values

Comment: There should be a button which can click and add options to hidden field

Comment: see this (at the same time when adding I need to append text to that hidden field): http://jsfiddle.net/hydride/Tg5ZC/2/

Comment: @Dushan did you check that 2 demo .or looking for new answer ?

Comment: append is what i want.not complete change

Comment: @Dushan textarea is a input element so you have to use val() not append

Comment: @Dushan if you use append that work  $('#services-view').append(val+"\n"); but do not use append in input tag

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#services-add" ).click(function() 
{                                
var insertText =$("#services option:selected").map(function () {
        return this.value;
}).get().join('|');
$('#services-view').val(insertText);
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Npm6w/1/